# Loading One Controller Per View AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, jsp

I have an Spring + AngularJS Web Application with the following angular file structure. 
mainmodule.js - where all config and routing's are
controller1.js
controller2.js

my main page is home.jsp where I imported all these files. As project goes bigger, I guess we have little over 50 files overall. So instead of dumping them in home.jsp, I would like to load them in it's corresponding view files. But when I tried to load controller1.js in corresponding JSP file, I get the below error.

```
[ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/ng/areq?p0=dashboardController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
```

Can someone help me identify what is the issue and how can I achieve this?

BTW I am using ui-router instead of default ngRoute.

Answer (score 3):

One way of dealing with that scenario is to define a resolve property on each route and assign it a function that returns a promise. The function can handle dynamically loading the script containing the target controller and resolve the promise once the load is complete. For example:

```
$routeProvider
.when('/customers',
    {
        templateUrl: '/app/views/customers.html',
        resolve: resolveController('/app/controllers/customersController.js')
    });
```

But the best solution to your problem would be to use **RequireJS** framework with AngularJS for dynamically loading controllers per view.
There is very interesting source that explains about this : http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs

RequireJS official website: [http://requirejs.org](http://requirejs.org/)

Comment: I would like to use the code which you post here, but I can't find resolveController method in ui-router. So can you post for any relevant site link?